# Can I reduce the MySQL speed to highlight which query is causing the slowness?

Tags: mysql, performance, benchmarking

I'm working on an API written in NodeJS and connecting to a MySQL 5.5 database.  On our live system, we have one query that's running at over 7 seconds.  We've traced this down to a couple of tables having over 5 millions records in and incorrectly indexed.

On our dev areas, we don't have that number of records.  I think I've identified the query that's causing the problem but, short of putting 5 millions records on my laptop (which will take ages to generate), I cannot prove it.

Is there a setting/technique that I can use to emulate having millions of database records without actually having the records in?

Comment: Are the problem queries flagged up in the slow query log? Can you use EXPLAIN to confirm where the problems are?

Comment: Not easily.  Part of the problem is that I don't have access to the live server (save a webpage that tells us the slow performing API methods).  Don't have access to any of the logging information

Comment: Ouch. If I was hit with such a problem I think I would be forced to write a small script to generate a large number of random dummy rows for the tables (this shouldn't take long). However if the database is badly designed and doing joins on complex parts of records then this would be less useful. Could you post the suspect query and the relevant table declares?

Comment: There's an inherent slowness in the API (need to do it through API as easier).  I've already written the script and it's merrily thrashing away. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original thought was of get a lot of data into the databases to highlight the issue.  I managed to get a million records in, just by leaving a script hammering the (dev) API overnight on.

The EXPLAIN function was pretty helpful.  I also found the EXPLAIN EXTENDED one pretty useful too.  However, neither of these highlighted the problem as it wasn't an indexing issue.

I also found the "RESET QUERY CACHE" function useful, as this cleared down the cached data for debugging purposes.

Some numpty had put a "WHERE DATE_FORMAT() = ''" in there.  Although quite annoyed at how long it took me to notice it (it was a Friday afternoon - be kind), I found and fixed the issue.  Thanks all.

The moral of the story is: **NEVER STICK FUNCTIONS IN WHERE CLAUSES!!!**

Comment: While this may solve your problem, it does NOT answer your own question, which is: **"Is there a setting/technique that I can use to emulate having millions of database records without actually having the records in?"**. Because of that, it is wrong to accept this answer.

Comment: Fair point.  However, none of the other answers actually addressed the question either.  Seeing as how this was how I solved the problem and does highlight a good point in database query design (ie, don't put functions in WHERE statements), it is appropriate to put this as the answer.

Also, the RESET QUERY CACHE **DOES** reduce the speed by clearing the cache.

Answer (score 2):

You can write Perl or Python script to populate your big test tables.
If you do it as single transaction, it should not take very long time.

If MySQL had `generate_series()` supported by PostgreSQL, it would have been much easier to do without scripting, but unfortunately, it doesn't :(.

However, you still can easily create big tables in MySQL (or any other SQL database) without scripting. Main idea is to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(16)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(name) VALUES ('Blah');
INSERT INTO mytable(name) SELECT name FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable(name) SELECT name FROM mytable;
...
```

Note that each next `INSERT` **doubles** table size.

Using this approach, this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80957/1) creates **1 million** test rows using about 20 lines of SQL in **less than 5 seconds**.

Comment: For many things you should be able to emulate generate_series() in MySQL with a table of integers from 0 to 9, which you can join against itself to get larger ranges of numbers

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can load in table statistics to from other databases - ie production to dev - in effect, mock the data volumes used when doing things like explain plans. Might be worth seeing if something equivalent exists under MySQL. It's not perfect, but would give you a better idea of what's going on under the hood.

Sorry I can't be more specific, I've just woken up and I haven't had tea yet.

Comment: Then have tea and answer with some references :)